# Nested items with Pivot -> children do not get the pivot data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I am trying to build a possibility of nested `items` for my `user` model.

Actually, every `user` can have many `items`, which can have `children` of their own type (`item`).

This is the user's relation to `item`:

```
   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
     */
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withPivot( 'value'');
    }
```

This is how the `children` are being resolved:

```
   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

Now - thanks to your help before - I can query the items with children:

```
$user->items()->whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```

This is the result:

> ```
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3247
>  all: [
>    App\Item {#3232
>      id: 2,
>      parent_id: null,
>      title: "Parent 1",
>
>      pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3235
>        user_id: 12,
>        user_item_id: 2,
>        value: "3",
>      },
>      children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3267
>        all: [
>          App\Item {#3270
>            id: 3,
>            parent_id: 2,
>            title: "Child 1",
>            created_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
>            updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
>          },
>          App\Item {#3272
>            id: 4,
>            parent_id: 2,
>            title: "Child 2",
>            created_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
>            updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
>          },
>        ],
>      },
>    },
>    App\Item {#3255
>      id: 5,
>      parent_id: null,
>      title: "Parent 2",
>      created_at: "2019-10-04 14:36:50",
>      updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:36:50",
>      pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3240
>        user_id: 12,
>        user_item_id: 5,
>        value: "50",
>      },
>      children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3266
>        all: [],
>      },
>    },
>  ],
> }
> ```

As you can see, the `parent` items got an pivot value - the `children` do not have any pivot data. How can I solve that? I learned, that `hasMany` does not provide pivot.

### My question

How can I add pivot data to nested `children` in this scenario?

Comment: The children will not have any pivot values since you are including it in a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you are already retrieving pivot between your `user` and the parent `item`. That's why you are getting the pivot attribute:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3247
 all: [
   App\Item {#3232
     id: 2,
     parent_id: null,
     title: "Parent 1", // <-----------

     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot { /** ... */ }
```

Now, you are eager loading the `children()` relationship of the queried `Items`, this is a `hasMany` relationship, that's why, those records doens't have a pivot element.

If you need to output this data you could just show the parent record for each child. Now, if you really need to add the parent pivot data to those children records, you could replicate the parent data mapping the retrieved collection and adding the data to each child element:

```
$users = $user->items()->whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();

$users = $users->map(function ($user) {
    $user->items->map(function ($parent) {
        $parent->children->map(function ($child) use ($parent) {
            $child->attribute = $parent->attribute;

            return $child;
        });

        return $parent;
    });

    return $user;
});
```

In this example, now every child `Item` will have the parent `attribute` replicated in them. The downside of this solution is that the parent data will be the same of the one added to the children data, I don't know if this is your desired output though.

Also, keep in mind that all this process is being made in memory, so you should always control the amount of data retrieved to avoid memory issues.

Another alternative, is to relate the children `Items` directly to the `User` objects. This way, every child item will have their own pivot data and you wouldn't need to eager load the `children()` relationship on your parent `Items`. Of course, you could group them to have the hierarchy that suits your needs, or just difference the parent and their children by the value of the `parent_id`.